# Create Panel at the bottom of a DataGridView based on X and Y

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Currently I have a dataGridView that displays a list of orders and what I want to do is create a new panel when a row is clicked on. This panel will be placed below the row and to the right slightly.

So far I have got it creating the new panel when the row is clicked on but it is creating the panel based on the Y coordinate from the first DataGridView

Here is what im using to try and get the X and Y.

```
dgvHistory.Controls.Add(pnl);

pnl.Location = new Point(dgvHistory.Location.X + 50, dgvHistory.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].ContentBounds.Bottom);

pnl.BringToFront();
```

Can you help me create the new panel PNL just below the row that was clicked in dgvHistory.

Thanks

Comment: So, `dgvHistory` is the `DataGridView` control. I've never tried adding a **Panel** control to a `DataGridView` control. Is this **Panel** being added as a new **DataGridViewRow**? What you are doing looks like it would throw up an error, but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `CellClick` event:

```
//CellClick event handler for your dgvHistory
private void dgvHistory_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
  var bounds = dgvHistory.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
  dgvHistory.Controls.Add(pnl);
  pnl.Location = new Point(0,bounds.Bottom);
  pnl.BringToFront();
}
```

In case you don't know how to register the `CellClick` event handler:

```
dgvHistory.CellClick += dgvHistory_CellClick;
```

Comment: Can a **Panel** be added to a **DataGridView** control?

Comment: Thank you, but I get the error when it is run, Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This happens on the line pnl.Location = new Point(0, bounds.Bottom);

Comment: @Karl I thought you have your `pnl` somewhere else. You want to add an empty panel to your datagridview?

Comment: @jp2code yes, `DataGridView` is just a normal control, we can add control onto it

Comment: @Karl: use `var pnl = new Panel();` first. You need to create it before you can use it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include where I was creating it in the method. Thats it going there now. Thank you very much :)